# Using DOMDocument to Pull XML Values

Tags: php, xml, soap, domdocument

I have a Soap Envelope response in XML format that I am trying to extract data from. I have been successful in extracting some data points; however, I am struggling with a couple. I have used `DOMDocument` in addition to a `getElementsbyTagName()` function so far.

I am trying to extract `<technicalSpecification>` data. Mainly, "Audi S4", "5 Door Wagon", "All-Wheel Drive", "Small Station Wagon", and "5.0".

Here is the XML (note.xml):

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <S:Body>
  <VehicleDescription country="US" language="en" modelYear="2008" bestMakeName="Audi" bestModelName="S4" bestStyleName="5dr Avant Wgn" xmlns="urn:description7b.services.chrome.com">
     <responseStatus responseCode="Successful" description="Successful"/>
     <vinDescription vin="WAUUL78E38A092113" modelYear="2008" division="Audi" modelName="S4" styleName="5dr Avant Wgn" bodyType="Wagon 4 Dr." drivingWheels="AWD" builddata="no">
        <WorldManufacturerIdentifier>Germany Audi Nsu</WorldManufacturerIdentifier>
        <restraintTypes>
           <group id="9">Safety</group>
           <header id="38">Air Bag - Frontal</header>
           <category id="1001">Driver Air Bag</category>
        </restraintTypes>
        <restraintTypes>
           <group id="9">Safety</group>
           <header id="38">Air Bag - Frontal</header>
           <category id="1002">Passenger Air Bag</category>
        </restraintTypes>
        <restraintTypes>
           <group id="9">Safety</group>
           <header id="39">Air Bag - Side</header>
           <category id="1005">Front Side Air Bag</category>
        </restraintTypes>
        <restraintTypes>
           <group id="9">Safety</group>
           <header id="39">Air Bag - Side</header>
           <category id="1007">Front Head Air Bag</category>
        </restraintTypes>
        <restraintTypes>
           <group id="9">Safety</group>
           <header id="39">Air Bag - Side</header>
           <category id="1008">Rear Head Air Bag</category>
        </restraintTypes>
        <marketClass id="53">Small Wagon</marketClass>
     </vinDescription>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>1</titleId>
        <value value="Audi S4" condition="-PT">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
        <value value="Audi S4" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>2</titleId>
        <value value="5 Door Wagon" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>6</titleId>
        <value value="All-Wheel Drive" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>7</titleId>
        <value value="Small Station Wagon" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
     <technicalSpecification>
        <titleId>8</titleId>
        <range min="5.0" max="5.0"/>
        <value value="5" condition="">
           <styleId>292015</styleId>
           <styleId>292016</styleId>
        </value>
     </technicalSpecification>
  </VehicleDescription>
```

Here is my PHP:

```
<html>
 <body>

  <?php

  $xml = file_get_contents('note.xml');

  $dom = new DOMDocument();
  $dom->loadXML($xml);


  $id = $dom->getElementsByTagName('WorldManufacturerIdentifier')->item(0);
  $vin = $dom->getElementsByTagName('titleId')->item(0);

  echo $id->textContent;
  echo "<br>";
  echo $vin->textContent;


  ?>

 </body>
</html>
```

This returns:

```
Germany Audi Nsu
1
```

My desirable return would be:

```
Germany Audi Nsu
Audi S4
5 Door Wagon
All-Wheel Drive
Small Station Wagon
5.0
```

Any ideas on how I can call these `technicalSpecification` variables would be great. Thanks so much!

**___________________________________________________________________________**

I am now attempting to pull data from the Exterior Color section. I am very close. I want the output to look like the following:

*Common Color Name* - *Technical Color Name*
So something like:

Red - Brilliant Red
Black - Brilliant Black

Here is the XML for the Exterior Color output:

```
     <exteriorColor colorCode="A2A2" colorName="Brilliant Black" rgbValue="131313">
        <genericColor name="Black" primary="true"/>
        <styleId>292015</styleId>
        <styleId>292016</styleId>
     </exteriorColor>
     <exteriorColor colorCode="C8C8" colorName="Brilliant Red" rgbValue="D23637">
        <genericColor name="Red" primary="true"/>
        <styleId>292015</styleId>
        <styleId>292016</styleId>
     </exteriorColor>
     <exteriorColor colorCode="8A8A" colorName="Deep Sea Blue Pearl" rgbValue="0F172A">
        <genericColor name="Blue" primary="true"/>
        <styleId>292015</styleId>
        <styleId>292016</styleId>
     </exteriorColor>
     <exteriorColor colorCode="F5F5" colorName="Dolphin Gray Metallic" rgbValue="53575F">
        <genericColor name="Gray" primary="true"/>
        <styleId>292015</styleId>
        <styleId>292016</styleId>
     </exteriorColor>
     <exteriorColor colorCode="T9T9" colorName="Ibis White" rgbValue="F4F5EF">
        <genericColor name="White" primary="true"/>
        <styleId>292015</styleId>
        <styleId>292016</styleId>
     </exteriorColor>
     <exteriorColor colorCode="1T1T" colorName="Imola Yellow" rgbValue="FFE242">
        <genericColor name="Yellow" primary="true"/>
        <styleId>292015</styleId>
        <styleId>292016</styleId>
     </exteriorColor>
     <exteriorColor colorCode="5B5B" colorName="Light Silver Metallic" rgbValue="A4A5A7">
        <genericColor name="Gray" primary="false"/>
        <genericColor name="Silver" primary="true"/>
        <styleId>292015</styleId>
        <styleId>292016</styleId>
     </exteriorColor>
     <exteriorColor colorCode="L8L8" colorName="Phantom Black Pearl" rgbValue="000000">
        <genericColor name="Black" primary="true"/>
        <styleId>292015</styleId>
        <styleId>292016</styleId>
     </exteriorColor>
     <exteriorColor colorCode="5N5N" colorName="Sprint Blue Pearl" rgbValue="1F3986">
        <genericColor name="Blue" primary="true"/>
        <styleId>292015</styleId>
        <styleId>292016</styleId>
     </exteriorColor>
```

Here is my PHP so far:

```
$finalColor = [];
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('exteriorColor') as $exColor){
   $genColor = $exColor->getElementsByTagName('genericColor')->item(0)->getAttribute("name");
   $colorNames = $exColor->getAttribute("colorName");
   $finalColor = $genColor."- ".$colorNames;
 }
   print_r($finalColor);
   echo "<br>";
```

This only retrieves the last color, not the full array. Been tweaking it for awhile with no success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same idea as you already have - using `getElementsByTagName()` to fetch the list of `<technicalSpecification>` elements and then within that you can then extract the `<value>` element.  Use `->getAttribute("value")` of the element to extract the value your after.

```
foreach ( $dom->getElementsByTagName('technicalSpecification') as $techSpec )   {
    echo $techSpec->getElementsByTagName('value')->item(0)->getAttribute("value");
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Which outputs...

```
Audi S4<br>5 Door Wagon<br>All-Wheel Drive<br>Small Station Wagon<br>5<br>
```

The only thing is that the last value is `5` and not `5.0` as this isn't in the same field as the other items.

**Update:**

You could store all of this data using the `<titleId>` value as the index and the value extracted above as the value against it.  So just build up an array as you go through...

```
$techData = [];
foreach ( $dom->getElementsByTagName('technicalSpecification') as $techSpec )   {
    $id = $techSpec->getElementsByTagName('titleId')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $techData [$id]= $techSpec->getElementsByTagName('value')->item(0)->getAttribute("value");
}
print_r($techData);
echo $techData[7];
```

which gives you...

```
Array
(
    [1] => Audi S4
    [2] => 5 Door Wagon
    [6] => All-Wheel Drive
    [7] => Small Station Wagon
    [8] => 5
)
Small Station Wagon
```

You could use XPath to do the same, but if your using more than 1 field, it's probably easier to do it this way (IMHO).

Comment: Thanks for your response! What if I want to create variables out of the data? Something like: `echo "Vehicle: ".$vehicle ;` which would output `Vehicle: Audi S4`.

Comment: Is there a way to call individual values without creating a `foreach` loop? For technicalSpecifications I want to use the `titleId`

Comment: I've added a new set of code which builds an array.

Comment: Brilliant! Exactly what I was looking for. Yes, I am taking this array data and forming it into a string. This seems like a concise way of doing so.

Comment: I am very close to requesting an array of exterior colors using similar logic. Currently it returns only the last exterior color in the data set. I edited the end of the question, adding the XML and PHP I am currently working on. Any help would be greatly appreciated!